# Correct way to install .NET assembly which contains implementation of System.Configuration.Install.Installer in WiX

Tags: .net, wix, installutil, wix3.11

I am building a WiX installer which needs to deploy a .NET assembly that contains an implementation of `System.Configuration.Install.Installer`.

The assembly is a plugin based on an SDK. The SDK defines an SDK-specific installer class which inherits from `System.Configuration.Install.Installer`. The assembly then subclasses the SDK's installer class, but the plugin's subclass is basically empty; all the custom install actions are actually in the SDK code. So, I'm not certain exactly what install actions the component actually performs during installation/uninstallation and would rather not attempt to replicate them using basic WiX components. I don’t own the SDK so I can’t easily [replace the `System.Configuration.Install.Installer` approach with DTF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16343297/porting-custom-install-actions-to-wix).

When installing the plugin manually, the assembly is registered using InstallUtil.exe, but it seems that calling InstallUtil.exe is not recommended for WiX-based installers.

What is the recommended way to install such .NET assemblies with WiX, when their self-install capabilities *do* need to be invoked and can’t be rewritten?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1891278/using-wix-to-put-an-assembly-into-both-the-gac-and-install-path.

Comment: That doesn’t seem relevant to the question. System.Configuration.Install.Installer and InstallUtil has nothing to  do with the GAC as far as I know.